# Run batch file to manually activate Windows 10 license key

Tags: cmd.exe

I want to know if my code is capable to run the command one after the other without interacting to click OK after activation of Windows or I should put addition command like " Start /wait cmd "....." on each of commandline.

```
@echo off

REM Windows Activation

Echo Activate Windows
set /p key="Input Windows Key : "

slmgr /ipk %key% /ato  && ^ 
wmic csproduct && ^
gpupdate /force

Modified

@echo off
REM Windows Activation
Echo Activate Windows
echo. =================================
set /p key="Input Windows KEY : "
echo. =================================


cscript %windir%\system32\slmgr.vbs /ato | find /i "successfully" &&  (goto status)

:status
Echo Check Windows Status
SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "WinVerAct="

For /f "tokens=*" %%W in ('
cscript /Nologo "C:\Windows\System32\slmgr.vbs" /xpr
') Do Set "WinVerAct=!WinVerAct! %%W"
if Not defined WinVerAct ( 
Echo:No response from slmgr.vbs
Exit /B 1
 
Echo Windows Version Activation Status:
Echo:"%WinVerAct:~1%"

wmic csproduct && ^
gpupdate /force

@exit /b
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid popups, use `cscript` to run the slmgr.vbs script.

```
cscript %windir%\system32\slmgr.vbs /ato
```

Comment: I hope I could get your point. Please advise if  /Nologo is needed after cscript...  Meantime I have changed my code hoping to view if activation is successful or else. Please advise if it works or not.

Comment: I have no idea what the purpose of your script is. What are you trying to make? Why does such a script need to exist?

Comment: You are right. I am making the unneccessary thing here. Thanks.